# weight decay or parameter shrinkage

Tags: machine-learning

The parameter shrinkage just like L2 , is known as weight decay .In sequential learning algorithms, it encourages weight values to decay towards zero, unless supported by the data. Why do we want to make weight values towards zero? or give me a example ,Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dataset for house prices with 1000 variables that have all a value of either `-1` or `+1`. So one example might be something like `(has_two_bedrooms=+1, is_close_to_highway=+1, has_golden_toilets=-1, has_tree_house=-1, ...)`. Now you want to classify whether the house sold for more than one million (`y=1`) or less than one million (`y=0`). You might use logistic regression for that and then have to set a weight for each variable. So you will have to make a judgement, whether e.g. `has_golden_toilets=+1` is a strong indicator for the house selling at a high value (high weight) or a weak indicator (low weight).

Now say you only end up with three examples that have `has_tree_house=+1` and all three houses sold for more than a million (`y=1`). Would you set the weight of that variable to a very high value? Probably not. You would more likely argue something like "That's an indication that `has_tree_house=+1` is a good indicator, but we don't know for sure yet. So let's set the weight to a medium value." L2 regression does that, because it's mathematically equivalent to using a prior for each weight, which is normal distributed around 0. So your expectation for each weight will be something like "probably 0, sometimes 0.25, rarely more than that". If you don't have a lot of data, the prior will play a big role in your judgement of the weight. In the case of the tree house example, it will punish high values, because there's not enough data to support such a high value. That prevents overfitting to the noise in your data.

You can also view it from a slightly different perspective: If you push your weights towards 0, then any classification will be a majority vote among rather equal variables. That decreases the damage that one overfitted parameter can possibly cause, as it only has a small influence on the total result.